# Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10 (Using ISO) - What about Existing Applications working in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04, system-installation

In my system I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and have downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 i386 ISO image.

If I install 14.04 by creating bootable pen drive, will all the applications existing in my system (13.10) continue to exist or do I have to upgrade using the software updater option for safety reasons?

What will be the pros and cons of both the upgrade methods?

1. Direct Software Updater
2. Using ISO to reinstall

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't affect your current environment to upgrade from the CD -- just choose the upgrade option in the installation type menu.

On the other hand, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will accomplish your purpose, but a good network connection is recommended.

-F

Answer (score 0):

There is an official recommendation how to do the upgrade on the documentation page, see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades